# How to show how many assertions were performed during an execution of tests in maven

Tags: maven-3, junit4, assertion

I have a lot of tests using JUnit 4 and Maven in Java. And im looking for a way to show how many assertions an specific test or the complete execution performed, is there a way to have that?

Currently im using "org.junit.Assert.*" and "org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*" to perform my assertions in my tests.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to AssertJ, but JUnit does not keep track of how many times the assert methods are called.

Keeping track of how many assertions have been made isn't a useful metric. You could have useful tests with no assertions (if you use `@Test(expected = SomeException.class)` and you can have not so useful tests with many assertions.

Comment: thanks for answering! yes i know, it was only to "show" because my boss asked me about that possibility to show how many assertions were performed like other unit tests in other languages here, only that.

Comment: @LeaChescotta I'm not aware of unit test libraries in other languages that test this. I would suggest to your boss that your team should look at code coverage and do good code reviews.